# Passing special character '&' as input in rest web service

Tags: web-services, rest

I have a rest web service whose url is

"/services/fetchData?id=value&name=value&date=......" 
In the above if my name has '&' character say 'H&M' then M is ignored.

Can you please suggest me how to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [urlencode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the parameter, so that `&` becomes `%26`.